# Range and string in Go template

Tags: go, templates

I am writing a Go template to create a yaml config:

my yaml config

```
logs:
  - type: file
    path: /opt/nomad/data/alloc/*/alloc/logs/*App1.stderr.*
    service: App1
    source: nomad
  - type: file
    path: /opt/nomad/data/alloc/*/alloc/logs/*App2.stderr.*
    service: App2
    source: nomad
```

My go template

```
logs:
{{- range $value := . -}}
- type: file
path: /opt/nomad/data/alloc/*/alloc/logs/*{{$value.Task}}.stderr.*
exclude_paths: /opt/nomad/data/alloc/*/alloc/logs/*{{$value.Task}}.stderr.fifo
service: {{$value.Task}}
source: nomad
{{end}}
```

How i need to change the template to get my yaml config

Comment: Just use an actual YAML library like https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Go yaml package enables programs to comfortably encode and decode YAML values.
You can use that: https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2